# How to use Google Analytics in Node Webkit desktop apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I am building a desktop app with Node-webkit, however I can't seem to get Google Analytics to work. I have tried the generated Javascript method, I've tried the NPM Google Analytics module. I can't seem to get pageview events to my analytics account.

What are the methods for tracking views/usage in a Node-Webkit desktop app?

Cheers

Comment: Your app doesn't have an FQDN, so Google can't track it.

Comment: Maybe you can use the same mechanism like mobile apps are using, to register events in Google Analytics, but maybe that will require compiling some library to work with Google SDK

Comment: To all those who say it can't be done, Atom editor uses Google Analytics. https://github.com/atom/metrics

Answer (score 3):

Google Analytics will only work on the domain that you have set in your account. Since node-webkit runs from the filesystem (file:// protocol), Google Analytics will not track any of these requests.

The only analytics service that I've found to work well with node-webkit is [gaug.es](http://get.gaug.es/), although they don't offer event tracking, which is unfortunate, but at least you get an idea of usage numbers.

EDIT:

I did some research and actually found this fork of Google Analytics that uses local storage instead of cookies, which will work with node-webkit: https://github.com/ggendre/GALocalStorage

It's using the old gajs instead of the new universal analytics, but it seems to function just fine.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method that i use for our Electon app is to include in production main html file the following iframe which is loading Google Analytics

```
<iframe src="http://link-to-your-html-that-loads-GA.html" width="0" height="0" style="visibility:hidden;display:none"/>
```

And the source code for html is:

```
<html>
<body></body>
    <script>
        (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
            i[r] = i[r] || function() {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
            a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async = 1;
            a.src = g;
            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-.......-..');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

This way you can see how many instances of your app are running and the locations for it and of course the total sessions number in day/month/year

Answer (score -1):

Use Woopra and their npm package. Super-awesome and they have 30k actions per month for free.

Install with

```
npm install --save woopra
```

Then use with:

```
var Woopra = require('woopra');

var woopra = new Woopra('konjekt.com', options);

//You have to identify your users with this approach.
woopra.identify('user@id.com', {
   visitorProperty: 'property'
}).push();
```

Woopra won't start tracking unless you push an event. Do so this way:

```
woopra.track('eventName', {
  eventProperty: 'property'
});
```

Personally I do a `"login"` event when a user logs in. If you don't have that concept, then make a random key that you store in the db which you use to identify that same user/instance.

Hope this helps :)